# My datetime picker from my model is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

The dateTime picker is not showing in the view for me to select a date for my ReturnDate.It wont give me the little arrow to select from a calendar (datetime picker) and it already fills in values. It just shows a textbox that contains : '0001/01/01 12:00:00 AM'

in my model this is my Returndate field:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }
```

my View is:

```
     <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
                </div>
            </div>
```

using jquery ui this is my new view:

```
@model FCproject.Models.Purchase

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <h4>Purchase</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "datepicker" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

But it still shows a textbox with no datetime picker.

Comment: Only Chrome supports `<input type="date"`

Comment: I have updated my question. please help

Comment: It now looks like you are using a jquery datepicker plugin (your `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attributes are not really necessary in this case). `$("#datepicker").datepicker();` will not work because you do not have an element with `id="datepicker"`. It needs to be `$("#ReturnedDate").datepicker();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running on IE that feature doesn't work, chrome works the best on ui's.

But if still gives you problem i'll suggest you use jquery datepicker:

your View (Modified):

```
    <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, new { @class ="control-label col-md-2", @id = "datepicker" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
                </div>
            </div>

   <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
    </script>
```

OR visit

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Dont forget to reference your ui scripts e.g: (Depending on your script version)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to MVC so I am not familiar with the referencing of jquery scripts, Where would i place the reference? will it be at the top of the view page only?

Comment: OK , first things first! 1. Have you install JQuery ui plugins? if not go to https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget , then it will show you how to install plugin, thereafter you will look for jqueryui. 2. When you done go Scripts folder then you will see 'jquery-ui-*version-' then just drag it to the top of your view. That should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Alright try the following. Remove the script out of Begin form so it can be initialized properly, also @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") take it to the top of your view
 and lastly you don't need [Datatype(Datatype.Date)] on your model. It is important to arrange your scripts and scripts reference properly. Hope this will work.